# Datatable session getting null

Tags: c#, session

I have bind a data-table through session and i have used same data-table to fill a grid-view. After particular amount of time my session is getting null in spite of session timeout kept as 60 minutes and session mode is in-proc.How to retain session for particular amount of time,For a longer duration ...

Comment: which programming languages are you using.and provide what have you tried

Comment: C# i am using.i  read an xml file into datatable and then used it to bind a gridview.Datatable i have kept in session and retrive later to compare rows of gridview which are selected using checkbox.After particular time datatable in session gets null...

Comment: did you increase the session timeout ?

Comment: yes i have kept it to 60 min in iis

Comment: could you pls post some relevant code, perhaps there is another problem causing your session to get null?

Comment: posting code is such horrible out here...asking for formatting which i am not used to

Comment: In IIS 7 i increased the timeout as well as script time out and it worked well for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was clearing the data-table below in the same page,because of that session used to get clear.session variables get process after pages are executed as whole